# Accessing/Modifying array in main file from route file/module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

(I am using express.js)

I have an array in my main file that I would like to modify (add elements to) from a separate file that contains a router for one of my endpoints:

Code in my main file (index.js):

```
let arr = [];
```

```
app.use('/create', require("./routes/.../module.js"));
```

Code in module.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  // here is where I would like to run code that would add something to the arr array in my main file
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Import the array and modify it. What's the question? I would use a separate file for the array to avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: Are you sure this route is written correctly? `"./routes/.../module.js"` ? How to you import `app` in `index.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using express.js, one way of passing a value to *route handlers* and is to use app.locals. By doing this, you can access `arr` in `module.js`. Here would be a simple example of that:

```
// index.js
app.locals.myArr = arr;


// module.js
module.exports.myhandler = function(req, res)
{
  let myArr = req.app.locals.myArr;
  //...
};
```

For more information on app.locals: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Hope this answer helps.